# Converting DateTime to string of series numbers in julia?

Tags: string, date, datetime, julia

I would like to know how can I store the Date Time from `Dates` as a series of continuous numbers.
For example:

```
using Dates
date=string(Dates.now())
println(date)

#Output --> 2021-06-15T19:39:17.171
```

I want it to be in the following format `20210615T193917171`.
May I know how can this be achieved in julia?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Dates.format](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Dates/#Dates.format-Tuple%7BTimeType,%20AbstractString%7D) function

```
using Dates

dt = Dates.now()
Dates.format(dt, dateformat"yyyymmdd\THHMMSSsss")
```

UPD: fixed answer using suggestions in comments.

Comment: 1. It is generally better to use a date format string `dateformat"yyyymmddTHHMMSSsss"` to create the format when expanding the string macro. 2. It is good to escape letters that are not to be interpreted as placeholders, e.g. `dateformat"yyyymmdd\THHMMSSsss"`. By default `T` is left as is, but e.g. the TimeZones.jl package adds functionality for `Z` in the format string so to avoid unexpected behavior it is good to be explicit about this.

Comment: A note on why `dateformat"..."` is preferable: because `@dateformat_str` is a macro, the format string will be turned into a `DateFormat` exactly once, at compile time, instead of being interpreted potentially multiple times at runtime.